# How to solve Redux Toolkit circular dependency action -> selector -> reducer -> action (.fullfilled of undefined)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

When defining my actions, reducer, and selectors I wanted to try to keep these in separate files so that my folder structure looks like this:

```
- store 
-- foo.actions.ts 
-- foo.reducer.ts 
-- foo.selectors.ts
```

In my `foo.actions.ts` file I define all of my actions which include AsyncThunk actions.
Some of these actions reference selectors in the `foo.selectors.ts` file. e.g.

```
import { selectById } from "./foo.selectors.ts"

export const barAction = createAsyncThunk<IFoo, { foo: IFoo }, { state: IFooState, rejectValue: IFoo }>(
    FooActionTypes.Bar,
    async (payload: {foo: IFoo}, {getState, rejectWithValue}) => {
        const existingFoo = selectById(getState(), payload.foo.id);
        ...
    }
);
```

The `foo.selectors.ts` file references the `foo.reducer.ts` file to use the entityAdapter that is used to create the initial state of the reducer. e.g.

```
import { fooAdapter } from "./foo.reducer.ts"

export const { selectById } = fooAdapter.getSelectors();
```

`foo.reducer.ts` then references `foo.actions.ts` in the createReducer function to reference the thunk types.

```
import { barAction } from "./foo.actions.ts"

export const fooAdapter = createEntityAdapter<IFoo>(...);
const initialState = fooAdapter.getInitialState();

export const reducer = createReducer(initialState, builder => 
    builder
        .addCase(barAction.fulfilled, ...)
):
```

This creates a circular dependency of `actions -> selectors -> reducer -> actions` which in turn causes the error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fulfilled')`

Is there any way to fix this whilst still maintaining the folder structure or is it unavoidable to have the thunks and reducer in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a method body to your builder callback could already help.

```js
export const reducer = createReducer(initialState, builder => {
    builder
        .addCase(barAction.fulfilled, ...)
}
);
```

Other than that you could move your entityAdapter out into a fourth file.

Comment: If I just added the method body to the callback I still got the issue. However, moving the adapter into a fourth `foo.store.ts` file solved the issue. Thank you so much :)